# Hashlib in Windows and Linux

Tags: python, windows, linux, performance, hashlib

I'm writing a p2p application in Python and am using the hashlib module to identify files with the same contents but different names within the network.

The thing is that I tested the code that does the hash for the files in Windows (Vista), with Python 2.7 and it's very fast (less than a second, for a couple of gigabytes). So, in Linux (Fedora 12, with Python 2.6.2 and Python 2.7.1 compiled by myself because I haven't found a rpm with yum) is so much slower, almost a minute for files less than 1gb.

The question is, **Why?** and **Can I do something to improve the performance in Linux?**

The code for the hash is

```
import hashlib
...

def crear_lista(directorio):

   lista = open(archivo, "w")

   for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(directorio):
      for f in files:
         #archivo para hacerle el hash
         h = open(os.path.join(root, f), "r")

         #calcular el hash de los archivos
         md5 = hashlib.md5()

         while True:
            trozo = h.read(md5.block_size)
            if not trozo: break
            md5.update(trozo)

         #cada linea es el nombre de archivo y su hash
         size = str(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, f)) / 1024)
         digest = md5.hexdigest()

         #primera linea: nombre del archivo
         #segunda: tamaño en KBs
         #tercera: hash
         lines = f + "\n" + size + "\n" + digest + "\n"
         lista.write(lines)

         del md5
         h.close()

   lista.close()
```

I changed the `r` by `rb` and `rU` but the results are the same

Answer (score 3):

You're reading the file in 64 byte (`hashlib.md5().block_size`) blocks and hashing them.

You should use a much larger read value in the range of 256KB (262144 bytes) to 4MB (4194304 bytes) and then hash that; this one [digup](https://idlebox.net/2009/digup/) program reads in 1MB blocks i.e.:

```
block_size = 1048576 # 1MB
while True:
    trozo = h.read(block_size)
    if not trozo: break
    md5.update(trozo)
```